# Building boost library

Tags: c++, python, boost, compilation

I'm trying to build boost library under Arch Linux

```
$ uname -a
Linux wincode 2.6.37-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 25 07:53:43 CET 2011 x86_64 AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5200+ AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux

$ python --version
Python 3.2

$ ls /usr/include/python
python2.7/   python3.2mu/

$ ls /usr/lib/python
python2.6/ python2.7/ python3.1/ python3.2/
```

I'm building it using aur-repo. The auto-compile script could be found [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/boost-devel/PKGBUILD).

Now I get:

```
./boost/python/*:50:23: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

at almost any file from boost.python library. So something is wrong with python and boost can't find it. At the end of the compiling I got:

```
...failed updating 336 targets...
...skipped 48 targets...
...updated 13264 targets...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick google search comes up with http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2006/04/13457.php.

Basically, add your python include directory to the include search paths.